# Excel If Function With More Condition with Match Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

i had a problem with if function with more condition and match function. May i had Solution?

Currently I try using this array formula but cannot get any result.

> {=IF(MATCH(A1;'6(AKK)'!$A$1:$A$100);"AKK";
>
> IF(MATCH(A1;'6(K3)'!$A$1:$A$100);"K3";
>
> IF(MATCH(A1;'6(Kesling)'!$A$1:$A$100);"Kesehatan Lingkungan";
>
> IF(MATCH(A1;'6(Kespro)'!$A$1:$A$100);"Kesehatan Reproduksi";
>
> IF(MATCH(A1;'6(Promkes)'!$A$1:$A$100);"Promosi Kesehatan";
>
> IF(MATCH(A1;'6(Epid)'!$A$1:$A$100);"Epidemiologi";
>
> IF(MATCH(A1;'6(Gizi)'!$A$1:$A$100);"Gizi Kesehatan Masyarakat";"Gagal")))))))}

For example, data in Main Sheet looks like below.

> ```
>       A                B
> ```
>
> 1. R.15.01.001   (This is Cell Formula)
> 2. R.15.01.002
> 3. R.15.01.003

For Example, data in Sheet "6(AKK)"

> ```
>       A
> ```
>
> 1    R.15.01.001
>
> 2    R.15.01.003
>
> 3    R.15.01.007
>
> 4    etc...

For Example, data in Sheet "6(K3)"

> ```
>       A
> ```
>
> 1    R.15.01.002
>
> 2    R.15.01.004
>
> 3    R.15.01.005
>
> 4    etc...

Every Sheet looks like that without same number in every sheet 6.
i need it for some Task. and i Hope i had a solution Here.

Comment: What is the purpose of this formula? Are you trying to return which sheet the value is found on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tere are two ways to accomplish this.

### Option 1 (clunky and less sophisticated, but perhaps easier to follow)

Because the `MATCH` function returns `#N/A` (or an error) when it can't find the match against a specific sheet, one solution is to wrap `ISNA` statements into your nested `IF` statements.

I have given you an example for the first 3 sheets here:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,'6(AKK)'!$A$1:$A$100,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,'6(K3)'!$A$1:$A$100,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,'6(KESLING)'!$A$1:$A$100)),"[See Note]","Kesehatan Lingkungan"),"K3"),"AKK")
```

**Note** - keep embedding the `IF(ISNA(MATCH ...` statements here. On the last one, place "Gagal" in this spot.

As you can see, it will get pretty long and ugly. Yet it will work.

Lastly, enter this a **regular** formula, not an array formula.

### Option 2 (more sophisticated and efficient, requires a little more initial input)

1. [Define a Named Range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4D0F13AC-53B7-422E-AFD2-ABD7FF379C64) as sList with the formula `=MID(TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1))&T(NOW()),FIND("]",TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1))&T(NOW()))+1,255)` (see more about [GET.WORKBOOK](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/getworkbook-help-in-macro-language-in-excel-2011/a359708d-b5b7-48ba-8d1e-c4114d4642d2?auth=1))
2. Set up a reference table that has the sheet names with the corresponding return values and Define this Range with a name of return_values

[image]

3. Enter this formula (as an array) into cell B1 `=VLOOKUP(INDEX(sList,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&sList&"'!$A$1:$A$100"),A1)>0)),return_value,2,0)`
   and drag down the rows for each value in column A

Comment: Yet it really Worked. But i have a problem for place "Gagal" in that spot. where i can place "Gagal"? =IF(ISNA(MATCH(C11;'6(AKK)'!$C$6:$C$105;0));IF(ISNA(MATCH(C11;'6(K3)'!$C$6:$C$105;0));IF(ISNA(MATCH(C11;'6(Kesling)'!$C$6:$C$105;0));IF(ISNA(MATCH(C11;'6(Kespro)'!$C$6:$C$105;0));IF(ISNA(MATCH(C11;'6(Promkes)'!$C$6:$C$105;0));IF(ISNA(MATCH(C11;'6(Epid)'!$C$6:$C$105;0));IF(ISNA(MATCH(C11;'6(Gizi)'!$C$6:$C$105;0));"Gizi Kesehatan Masyarakat");"Epidemiologi");"Promosi Kesehatan");"Kesehatan Reproduksi");"Kesehatan Lingkungan");"K3");"AKK")       Because the last one on Gizi false.

Comment: Ah... i found it... Thanks for the Solution... it Really Help Us So Much...